# Batch Apex to insert json data into the Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, schedulebatch

**Have Json after API callout as given below**.. **need to insert into database using batch apex**. **How to do this ??** can anyone help me ??
Bit Aware of batchable interface and Batch class.

```
{
"accounts" : {
    "data" : [{
            "access_token" : "EAACEdEostrtre0cBAN0i40rLaxz1E79BH5QngiwStR7DoaQsX7ZAFJ1QLm66fo07W76WYGqU4X1GjC8uqqcGawOA6MBms5gZAfo0VQA4kch3ltoIPd86zBK1ecLzznS5hdTizYZBYqpsIse9jVqA0PZCIIeVR6WAA46sTjJZBW8ZBnqgZDZD",
            "category" : "Organization",
            "name" : "Busyday",
            "id" : "1616378787867178658991",
            "perms" : [
                "ADMINISTER",
                "EDIT_PROFILE",
                "CREATE_CONTENT",
                "MODERATE_CONTENT",
                "CREATE_ADS",
                "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "paging" : {
        "cursors" : {
            "before" : "MTYxNjrtrtM2NzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD",
            "after" : "MTYxNjMretrt2NzE3ODY1ODk5MQZDZD"
        }
    }
},
"id" : "1150203232221712395"
}
```

Converted into wrappper class. https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

```
public class facebookpages {
public static void consumeObject(JSONParser parser) {
    Integer depth = 0;
    do {
        JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if (curr == JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
            curr == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
            depth++;
        } else if (curr == JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
            curr == JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            depth--;
        }
    } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
}

public Accounts accounts {get;set;} 
public String id {get;set;} 

public facebookpages(JSONParser parser) {
    while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String text = parser.getText();
            if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                if (text == 'accounts') {
                    accounts = new Accounts(parser);
                } else if (text == 'id') {
                    id = parser.getText();
                } else {
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Root consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                    consumeObject(parser);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Paging {
    public Cursors cursors {get;set;} 

    public Paging(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'cursors') {
                        cursors = new Cursors(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Paging consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Cursors {
    public String before {get;set;} 
    public String after {get;set;} 

    public Cursors(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'before') {
                        before = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'after') {
                        after = parser.getText();
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Cursors consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Data {
    public String access_token {get;set;} 
    public String category {get;set;} 
    public String name {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public List<String> perms {get;set;} 

    public Data(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'access_token') {
                        access_token = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'category') {
                        category = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'name') {
                        name = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'id') {
                        id = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'perms') {
                        perms = new List<String>();
                        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            perms.add(new String(parser)); 
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Data consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Accounts {
    public List<Data> data {get;set;} 
    public Paging paging {get;set;} 

    public Accounts(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'data') {
                        data = new List<Data>();
                        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            data.add(new Data(parser));
                        }
                    } else if (text == 'paging') {
                        paging = new Paging(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Accounts consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public static facebookpages parse(String json) {
    return new facebookpages(System.JSON.createParser(json));
}
}
```

Comment: Deserialize the values from JSON string, as per desired mapping load data in object and insert. Are you facing any challenges?

Comment: |DEBUG|facebookpages:[accounts=Accounts:[data=(Data_Z:[id=746973509, name=Sneakpick, picture=Picture:[data=Data:[is_silhouette=true, url=https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/405770_1015012_7345_n.png?oh=b9d40ebc96d0992e55ccc5a16d678&oe=5873E1]]], 
Data_Z:[id=1616367158991, name=Busyday, picture=Picture:[data=Data:[is_silhouette=true, url=https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/399548_10197789_11042_n.png?oh=82d555c70ae9e2ad123aaebbc331&oe=58E46A]]]), paging=Paging:[cursors=Cursors:[after=MTYxNjM2NzE3Y1ODMQZDZD, before=NzQ2OTczNDTI2A5]]], id=11470363662]

Comment: Deserialized perfectly.. have object need to pass in that batch class.But how ?

Comment: Or Do i need to add the deserialized object in start method ? How ?

Comment: @Innodel for security reasons,  you may want to delete the access_token from this post.

Comment: @ArpiJakab The token is already edited by me before posting the post. this token is fake token. Secure is secure.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work providing the amount of data you are processing can fit within the 12M [heap governor limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm):

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<Object> {

    private String jsonString;

    public MyBatchable(String jsonString) {
        this.jsonString = jsonString;

    public Iterable<Object> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return facebookpages.parse(jsonString).accounts.data;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Object> scope) {
         Account[] inserts = new Account[] {};
         for (Object o : scope) {
             facebookpages.Data d = (facebookpages.Data) o;
             // You'll have to figure out how the data maps to the Account
             // (or other SObject type) you want to create
             inserts.add(new Account(
                     Name = d.name,
                     Category__c = d.category,
                     ...
                     ));
         }
         insert inserts;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

This is using the [version of the start method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) that returns an `Iterable` rather than a `QueryLocator`.